# WPF : Filling DataGrid cell with a shape

Tags: wpf, datagrid, cell, shapes

Is there a simple way to fill a Datagrid cell with a shape?

I want my cell to be filled with a red circle.

From the properties on cell style I saw the background property which needs a brush, is it possible to use it with a shape somehow?

Thanks

Comment: you can put in image of red circle.

Comment: To answer your question with as much effort as you put into asking... yes, there is. If you want a better answer, you need to ask a better question. You need to provide more details of your requirements... should there be a shape in every cell, or just one? What data is bound to the `DataGrid`? Most importantly, what have *you* tried already?

Comment: I want this to specific cells, Datagrid is bound to a collection on DataGridColumn which is generated dynamically, I can access every cell based on a condition I have in a converter connected to a cell style, I already tried creating a DrawingBrush and returning it to the background property but failed, for now I'm able to fill the cells only with colors of type Brushes

Comment: Create a `DataTemplate` that hosts a circle. Set the DataGridCell.Template.

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
<!-- DataGrid column displays a red circle in each cell -->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Red" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

More information can be found here:
[Adding a small, coloured rectangle in DataGrid cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474828/adding-a-small-coloured-rectangle-in-datagrid-cell)